# How to retry try statement on Node properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, steam

Heres my raw code, basically it tries to accept "Trade offer" and if it fails it gets declined. How do I make it retry this statement on same "Trade offer" 10 times with a couple second interval, and if after that it still fails, decline the offer?

```
try {
    offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err, log) {
        if (err) { 
            helper.log('Error accepting trade offer ' + offer.tradeofferid, 891, err);
            offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function() {
                currentGameOffers.splice(currentGameOffers.indexOf(offer.tradeofferid), 1);
            });     
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Since it's asynchronous: Recursion. Notice that the `try`/`catch` doesn't work anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Something with a `setTimeout()` on the callback. A promise or even the ES2017 async-await (babel, TypeScript) helps you get a cleaner code. Also, because an error is propagated in the callback, there's no need to use a `try` block, unless the api you're using could fail right away, but usually not in callback-passing style.

```
function putOffer(maxRetries) {
    offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(err, log) {
        if (err) { 
            if (maxRetries > 0) {
                setTimeout(function () { putOffer(maxRetries - 1); }, 2000);
                return;
            }
            helper.log('Error accepting trade offer ' + offer.tradeofferid, 891, err);
            ...
            return;
        }
    });
}

putOffer(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for my ask but if i change my statement from "try" to "function" like you posted, will that affect my code in a bad way? Cause theres "catch" statements in my code aswell later on

Comment: A try/catch usually catches bugs in your code only, like setting to a undeclared variable. In asynchronous code usually there's no need for it. It's very rare for a try catch in your code, unless you yourself like to perform validations and `throw`. I would say take a look at the api to see if it can throws. Either way you need to have something useful to do in the catch clause. Otherwise you just need a global uncaughtException handler https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

Comment: I don't really know what "throw" is but my if my app gets some load on API it crashes and ruins whole mongodb and it has to start over

Comment: Heres how it looks like on console:

`[21:20:34:53] Message: "Checking min deposite - 1674091486"`

`undefined:1`

`�`

`^`

Comment: I'd let it crash and restart with the help of a tool like `pm2` or `forever`, to restart the app. Or you could "handle" it then with a try/catch, or throttle requests...

Comment: I'm using forever right now, but if it keeps crashing, my site will be useless, cause its all about sockets and live numbers.

Comment: okay, but a plain try/catch swallowing the error isn't a good thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to expand slightly on @André Werlang answer. My issue was that I was having to make hundreds of calls (due to API limitations) and was also utilizing `Promise.all()` to return all of the data once all Promises were complete. This may not be ideal or even a proper usage of Promise.all() - but in regards to error handling it worked the way I expected:

```
const requestPromise = (req) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const maxRetries = 5;
        function tryRequest(retries) {
                // try a request (http)
                if (someErr) {
                    setTimeOut(()=>{ tryRequest(maxRetries--); }, 2000);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    // resolve your Promise
                    resolve(data);
                }
        }
    });
}
```